# Issue with STATIC FILES on Django

Tags: python, django, static

I cloned a project from github where they were using some "special configuration" for static files, using instead of '/static/', '/static_in_env/', I didn't understand very well why they were doing that, so I decided to change it to what appears on most docs, or tutorials which is the following config.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Just for giving some extra info:

inside TEMPLATES, besides other things, I have:

```
 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

which the site seems to read okay(ish), since the problem I have is it renders the templates but without the css

I also have inside INSTALLED_APPS 'django.contrib.staticfiles'

On the left, (on vscode) I have a folder named static which looks a bit darker than the rest (which I don't know what it means)

I'm on a venv created with python 3,
when I run

```
python --version
```

it tells me I'm on python 3.6.9 which seems ok to me.

I also already ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

previously having copied manually all the static files into assets also, so the collectstatic command puts them wherever they should be for the program to read them, and it told me all files had been moved (or collected, I'm not sure what it says after collectstatic).

This is one of the many static files it doesn't find (it literally seems like it can't get into that folder)

[2020-07-17 04:33:31,265] log: WARNING - Not Found: /static/css/style.default.css
[17/Jul/2020 04:33:31] "GET /static/css/style.default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77

I also tried chmod 774 that folder, and also going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/static
it returns

> Not Found
> The requested resource was not found on this server.

As the last thing, I remember having tried with a command that I can't find now, because I copied from some forum that I can't find, but that was supposedly to get you the address of where django is actually looking for the file,
I'm just certain the command included the word verbose. And when I executed it, it seemed as if django was reading the static files from the django installation or something inside the venv (although I'm not completely sure, and since I haven't been able to find that command again, which I'd appreciate if someone can tell me, I can't confirm.).

I've just ran out of ideas, I could restart the project or try again, but this is killing me, since I'm thinking, what is wrong I've double checked every single piece and it still doesn't work.

- static folder is at the same level as templates folder and assets and the apps (same as manage.py).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to access the static file via a URL.

The "intelligent static files" you were referring to likely used a third-party resource like AWS which serves the static files. If you want to go to localhost:8000/static/file.ext

Try adding this to the bottom of your urls.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, I had debug set to false in development (to experiment), and had that piece of code inside urls.py, inside  if debug: 
so it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

My django project worked fine, serving static files, both from the command line and on Pycharm. On VSCode, static files where not served.
My code looked like this:

```
import os.path

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join('static'),
]
```

My static files where stored in a folder named "static" right below the django project folder.

It worked fine after I changed STATICFILES_DIRS to an absolute path, like the code below:

```
import os.path

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
]
```

Now its working without issue or any other necessary changes to code or configuration.